# How to store the number of likes from a HTML "icon button"

Tags: php, html, css, sql, ajax

I am a beginner in webdevelopment, i am doing for fun an website. Now I achieved everything I want, but one thing is still open. I have searched a lot (read about DB/Ajax etc) but did not found anything which is working out for me.

I have a specific site which are only images. I would like to that a person can Like an image without registration, but I need to store this like in a Database or something like that. What my code is now:

```
<div class="like">
<i onclick="Toggle(this)" id="btn1" class="far fa-heart"></i>
</div>
```

This is the class, when you click on the button, it should change the color to a red. (This is already achieved). But if I refresh the page, the like is not kept. Can someone give me tips with an example?

Comment: You need to use a database to be able to save all likes. But I'm guessing that multiple people should be able to like an image so you also need to know _who_ liked it. How you'll do that depends on your rules. Should they be able to vote again the next time they visit the site? If yes, then you can store it in a session/cookie/local storage and check that when outputting the HTML. If the answer is "no", then things becomes much more complicated since they are anonymous (you don't have a good way of identifying the user).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, an external database should be used to save the data.

In your simple case, you can use local client storage to save the data. This article may be helpful:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use AJAX for request to save in database.
first search about AJAX in JS or Jquery.
then you need backend language eg : PHP,python,ASP...
and with language can save your data in database (database eg : mysql,mariadb,...)

maybe that links help you:
Ajax with Jquey: https://learn2torials.com/a/what-is-ajax

---

Ajax with JS : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

---

use database with PHP : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-insert-form-data-into-database-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some JavaScript to a varying degree of complexity depending on what your end goal is.

### 1. Serving each user on an individual basis only

###### i.e. What user `A` liked doesn't affect what's shown to user `B`

It's more of `Save to favorites` type of scenario, in which case you can simply store the `like` counts in a given user's `localStorage`. This MDN page would be a good starter for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

### 2. Persisting the accumulative values to the open web

###### i.e. What user `A` liked counts to what user `B` sees

This is closer to a social media scenario, where everyone gives a `like` which is visible to everyone else. As others mentions, you'd need a certain type of database or storage online. With the JAMstack approach there are simpler solutions than traditional DBs with traditional servers. I'd recommend simple cloud DB solutions like Firebase https://firebase.google.com/